# How to refer to the input document context within the context of an external document?

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<xsl:template match="extnode">
    <xsl:if test="/topnode/value">

    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-template select="document('external.xml')/exttopnode/extnode"/>
</xsl:template>
```

In the example above, the context on line 2 (xsl:if) will be with respect to document('external.xml'). But what I really want is to test an element from the input XML. Is there a way to refer to the input document?

Currently I'm forced to pass the entire node tree of the input document as an argument to the template, and I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a convenient and simple solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the example above, the context on
>   line 2 (`xsl:if`) will be with respect
>   to `document('external.xml')`. But
>   what I really want is to test an
>   element from the input XML. Is there a
>   way to refer to the input document?

**Whenever I find myself in such situation, I prefer to have a global variable** (say named `$vMainDoc`) that is accessible anywhere in the whole transformation without the need to pass a parameter:

```
<xsl:variable name="vMainDoc" select="/"/>
```

**Then your code would become**:

```
<xsl:template match="extnode">
    <xsl:if test="$vMainDoc/topnode/value">

    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```